# Plot wordfish thetas (not scaled)

Tags: ggplot2, quanteda

I have conducted a wordfish analysis with quanteda.

Through the function textplot_scale1d() I was able to plot the estimated thetas.

```
# run wordfish
tmod_wf <- textmodel_wordfish(example_DFM, dir = c(2, 1))

# plot the estimated thetas (scaled/ordered):
# y axis -> the documents
# x axis -> the estimated thetas
tmod_wf %>% 
  textplot_scale1d(margin = c("documents", "features"))
```

Now I would like to plot a graph in which the estimated thetas appear in the y axis and the documents appear in the x axis (not ordered based on their estimated thetas).

`plot(tmod_wf$theta, xlab = "Documents", ylab = "Estimated_thetas")`

the above line creates the following scatterplot:

[scatterplot (thetas and documents)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPKSy.jpg)

The thetas are on the y axis while the documents are on the x axis (ordered as they appear in the corpus). The scatterplot suits my needs, however is rather empty, I would like to embellish it: highlight some documents, change the dots' size etc...

Is it possible to convert such a plot to ggplot?

I tried the following:

```
tmod_wf$theta %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = docs, y = theta))
```

However, the following error appears:

```
Error in `fortify()`:
! `data` must be a <data.frame>, or an object coercible by `fortify()`, not a double
  vector.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data has to be data.frame

Try to do this:

```r
tmod1 <- textmodel_wordfish(quanteda::data_dfm_lbgexample, dir = c(1,5))

# extract theta and docs
df = tibble(theta = tmod1[["theta"]],
            docs = tmod1[["docs"]])
```

Then plot with ggplot:

```r
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = theta, y = docs, fill = -theta)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdYlGn") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: bar plot]

Comment: Nice! Can't find the function `textmodel_wordfish` though. Which package do I need?

Comment: You have to install this library: `install.packages("quanteda.textmodels")
library(quanteda.textmodels)`